# Uncaught exception in firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I'm getting an uncaught exception in firefox. ([12:53:36.595] uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id^=ctl00_ContentBody_cblAtmDebitCards)  This is in the javascript of my page that im writing in C#

```
[12:53:36.595] uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id^=ctl00_ContentBody_cblAtmDebitCards
```

This is the whole call

```
 $.validator.addMethod('CheckOneCreditCard', function () {
            var cards = $('input[id^=<%=cblCreditCards.ClientID%>], input[id^=<%=cblAtmDebitCards.ClientID%>');

            if (cards.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                    if (cards[i].checked) return true;
                }
                return false;
            } else return false;
        });
```

I'm using validator from http://jqueryvalidation.org/  Every combo I've tried has failed. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Did you forget to close a bracket in the selector line?

Comment: Always look at the generated markup, not the serverside code!

Comment: Any reason you're using `$("input[id^=...` instead of `$("#...` for the selector when searching for IDs? `ClientID` will return the ID of one control, and IDs should be unique to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute values in jQuery selectors must be quoted.
Put quotes around your ID.

You're also missing a `]`.

Comment: var cards = $('input[id^="<%=cblCreditCards.ClientID%>"], input[id^="<%=cblAtmDebitCards.ClientID%>"]');   - This worked great! I'm a bonehead sometimes :) thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the closing `]`

```
var cards = $('input[id^=<%=cblCreditCards.ClientID%>], input[id^=<%=cblAtmDebitCards.ClientID%>]');
```

Additionally, since you are using the actual control ID, I would change the selector to:

```
var cards = $('#<%=cblCreditCards.ClientID%>, #<%=cblAtmDebitCards.ClientID%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cards = $('input[id^=<%=cblCreditCards.ClientID%>], input[id^=<%=cblAtmDebitCards.ClientID%>']);
```